# Excel import looping through non-existing rows after deleting one row using Libreoffice

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I have a Laravel 9 application which allows the import of xslx spreadsheets using Laravel Excel.

I was testing the imports with an Excel file the client has given me. Everything was OK, until I face the following problem: When deleting a row using LibreOffice Calc, the import never ends as it detects more than one million rows.

The problem doesn't happen if using Microsoft Excel.

I tried to reach the PhpSpreadsheed class and using its setReadDataOnly() method, by hooking on the beforeExport event or using macros within the AppServiceProvider, but the problem persists.

```
public function registerEvents(): array { 
     return [ 
        BeforeExport::class => function(BeforeExport $event) { 
            $event->reader->getProperties()->setReadDataOnly(true); 
        }, 
    ]; 
}
```

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    Paginator::useBootstrapFive();
    Reader::macro('setCreator', function (Reader $reader, string $creator) {
        $reader->getDelegate()->setReadDataOnly(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Ever try out `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension()` to dump out how much rows being effected after the deletion ? I am mainly on Excel and I did found a behavior of how phpspreadsheet reading rows : it is reading until the rows/cols that you ever touch on it and then *save* the file, even if you just click on some empty rows and never input anything on it. My guess is when you open Excel using LibreOffice Calc and *save*, somehow all rows become affected and that's why it detects more than 1 mil rows, which Excel has a max of 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: I just tried with a simple test, new excel with few rows 1,2,3 and save -> Open in LibreOffice Calc remove a row and save -> try open the Excel file again and you guess what : **PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108872 bytes)**, maybe the result prove my assumption. So my suggestion is, use Excel on excel, use LibreOffice only for Ods, and etc.